# Postgres FATAL: could not open relation mapping file

Tags: postgresql

I installed postgress.app on mac os
when I try to connect to console :
psql -h localhost
I got this problem .

> psql -h localhost psql: FATAL:  could not open relation mapping file
>   "global/pg_filenode.map": No such file or directory

Any ideas how to solve this ?

Comment: Did you run `initdb`?

Comment: Yes I did. I am trying now to re-install everything.

Comment: If the datadir exists, then it's probably a file permission problem. The user running the postgres service probably does not have the rights to access the files (or is looking in the wrong place)

Comment: what do you suggest to do ?

Comment: Is there data you care about on that database instance? If so [read and act on the guidance for database corruption](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when I tried to reinstall PostgreSQL on RHEL6 using a Chef cookbook. In my case this seems to have been due to an incorrect manual uninstallation of PostgreSQL. I used this command to find the offending files that disrupted my installation:

```
find / -user postgres
```

And then I deleted all the files I found as they were owned by postgres and I did not even have a postgres user. To be on the safe side I also rebooted the machine and after that it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by a running postgresql and me running initdb a few times. Killing all postgresql processes, removing the pgsql/data directory, running initdb and then starting postgresql again solved the issue.